# Program not running when double clicked but runs from cmd?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, window, double-click

I have made a python gui using tkinter and i have been running it through the commandline. But when i tried to open it by double clicking, it shortly shows the window but exits again. I tried commenting out all the places where it uses images thinking that it is because it dosent have file-editing permissions when its run by double click and it worked! But i need to use images in the gui, anyone have solutions?

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Krypto Coin")
root.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
root.configure(bg="#112233")

Frame = tk.Frame(root, width=1200, height=800, bg="#112233")
Frame.grid(columnspan=3, rowspan=5)

icon = Image.open('icon_round.png')
icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(icon)
icon_label = tk.Label(image=icon, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
icon_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.2, anchor="center")

text = tk.Label(root, text="Welcome to Krypto Coin (KTC)", bg="#112233", fg="#ffffff", font=("Arial", 32))
text.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.45, anchor="center")
text = tk.Label(root, text="Enter id of the receiver and amount", bg="#112233", fg="#ffffff", font=("Arial", 24))
text.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center")

def trasfer_button_pressed():
    time.sleep(0.1)
    trasfer_button_text.set("Loading...")
    trasfer_button.configure(state="disable")
    trasfer_button.configure(bg="#112233")
    input_id.configure(state="disable")
    input_amount.configure(state="disable")

def trasfer_button_enter(e):
    if trasfer_button_text.get() == "Transfer":
        trasfer_button.configure(bg="#334455")

def trasfer_button_leave(e):
    if trasfer_button_text.get() == "Transfer":
        trasfer_button.configure(bg="#223344")

trasfer_button_text = tk.StringVar()
trasfer_button = tk.Button(root, textvariable=trasfer_button_text, command=lambda:trasfer_button_pressed(), bg="#223344", fg="#ffffff", width=15, height=1, font=("Arial", 24), borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
trasfer_button_text.set("Transfer")
trasfer_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.65, anchor="center")
trasfer_button.bind("<Enter>", trasfer_button_enter)
trasfer_button.bind("<Leave>", trasfer_button_leave)

input_id = tk.Entry(root, width=48, font = "Arial 14", bg="#334455", fg="#ffffff", borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
input_id.insert(0, "ID")
input_id.place(relx=0.45, rely=0.8, anchor="center", height=30)

input_amount = tk.Entry(root, width=20, font = "Arial 14", bg="#334455", fg="#ffffff", borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
input_amount.insert(0, "Amount")
input_amount.place(relx=0.65, rely=0.8, anchor="center", height=30)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: try add function `main()` and insert code to here. in  the bottom add `if __name__ == "__main__": main()`
its maybe help you

Comment: The current working directory may not set to the path of the script when using double-click to execute it, so any resource loading using relative path will fail.

Comment: what do you mean by this, and how do i fix it?

Comment: When you open a command shell and change directory to the script path.  Then the *current working directory* is the script path.  When you run your script now, it works because those relative paths can be accessed.  However if you change directory to other path, the *current working directory* will be the new path.  When you run your script again by specifying the full path of the script, it will fail because the relative path in your script do not exists under the *current working directory*.